# Generating random number by length of blocks of data in R data frame

Tags: r, random, split, simulation

I am trying to simulate n times the measuring order and see how measuring order effects my study subject. To do this I am trying to generate integer random numbers to a new column in a dataframe. I have a big dataframe and i would like to add a column into the dataframe that consists a random number according to the number of observations in a block.

Example of data(each row is an observation):

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3), 
                 B=c("x","b","c","g","h","g","g","u","l"), 
                 C=c(1,2,4,1,5,7,1,2,5))


  A B C
1 1 x 1
2 1 b 2
3 1 c 4
4 2 g 1
5 2 h 5
6 3 g 7
7 3 g 1
8 3 u 2
9 3 l 5
```

What I'd like to do is add a D column and generate random integer numbers according to the length of each block. Blocks are defined in column A.

Result should look something like this:

```
df <- data.frame(A=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3), 
                 B=c("x","b","c","g","h","g","g","u","l"), 
                 C=c(1,2,4,1,5,7,1,2,5),
                 D=c(2,1,3,2,1,4,3,1,2))

> df
  A B C D
1 1 x 1 2
2 1 b 2 1
3 1 c 4 3
4 2 g 1 2
5 2 h 5 1
6 3 g 7 4
7 3 g 1 3
8 3 u 2 1
9 3 l 5 2
```

I have tried to use R:s `sample()` function to generate random numbers but my problem is splitting the data according to block length and adding the new column. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, and well done for providing a reproducible example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really easy with `ddply` from `plyr`.

```
ddply(df, .(A), transform, D = sample(length(A)))
```

The longer manual version is:

Use `split` to split the data frame by the first column.

```
split_df <- split(df, df$A)
```

Then call `sample` on each member of the list.

```
split_df <- lapply(split_df, function(df) 
{
  df$D <- sample(nrow(df))
  df
})
```

Then recombine with

```
df <- do.call(rbind, split_df)
```

Comment: @MarkusKorhonen If an answer is working well for you, click the checkmark next to it to "accept" it and indicate that you're not still hoping for more answers.

Comment: @shujaa Sry, I'm new here. Thx for the tip. I marked an answer.

Comment: @MarkusKorhonen, no worries, welcome to the site! And, as Richie already commented, nice work asking a high-quality first question.

Answer (score 4):

It can be done easily with `ave`

```
df$D <- ave( df$A, df$A, FUN = function(x) sample(length(x)) )
```

(you could replace length() with max(), or whatever, but length will work even if A is not numbers matching the length of their blocks)

Comment: Nice demonstration of `ave()`'s capabilities. It's a real pity that such as useful function has such a terribly misleading name. Even the documentation at `?ave` is not much better at communicating what it really does.

Comment: yes, it's a bit of a shame... I'm guessing they were originally going with (ave)rage and that's how it works when you don't specify `FUN`.

Comment: This one's a great solution too! Thx for help!

Answer (score 1):

One simple way:

```
df$D = 0

counts = table(df$A)

for (i in 1:length(counts)){
    df$D[df$A == names(counts)[i]] = sample(counts[i])
}
```